# Using IF or Case to determine what field to use in a WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with

```
Name   EnteredDateID  RecvdDateID

A      20140901       20240901    
B      20140901       20140901
C      20140901       20140901
D      20140901       20140901
E      20140901       20110901
F      20140901       20140901
G      20140901       20110901
```

I need to write a query that would do the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE
```

and this is where I'm falling over

```
IF RecvdDateID > GETDATE() THEN USE 
EnteredDateID > 20140630 
ELSE USE THE 
RecvdDateID  > 20140630
```

So I would end up with

```
Name   EnteredDateID  RecvdDateID

A      20140901       20240901    
B      20140901       20140901
C      20140901       20140901
D      20140901       20140901
F      20140901       20140901
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA WHERE
20140630 < 
CASE WHEN RecvdDateID > GETDATE() THEN 
    EnteredDateID  
ELSE 
    RecvdDateID    
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE (RecvdDateID > GETDATE() AND EnteredDateID > 20140630)
    OR (RecvdDateID <= GETDATE() AND RecvdDateID  > 20140630)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just to make life simpler you can use a user defined function and use it in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE dbo.MyCriteriaMatches(RecvdDateID,EnteredDateId) =1
```

and you can create the function `MyCriteriaMatches` where you can return 1 in the case you have highlighted above else 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This might be simpler, but it also adds a dependency on another database object; it would also likely be less efficient; due to the overhead of the function call for every row in the table, and also the inability to use an index to satisfy the predicate.